# Is there a blank indentation in Python?

Tags: python, indentation

Over the course of development it sometimes becomes necessary to temporarily comment out blocks of code for testing purposes.

Sometimes these comments require re-indentation of code fragments that could become difficult to take back later without introducing errors.

I was wondering whether there was a "blank indentation" operator, sort of the opposite of "pass"

**Example:**

```
def func(x):
    if x == 0:
        print("Test")
```

For testing, I am commenting out the "if" temporarily, which breaks indentation:

```
def func(x):
    # if x == 0:
        print("Test")
```

I want to avoid re-indentation like this, since it's only a temporary change and it could mess up more complex code:

```
def func(x):
    # if x == 0:
    print("Test")
```

**Question:** Is there something like this?

```
def func(x):
    # if x == 0:
    force_indent:
        print("Test")
```

Of course, I could do the following, I was just wondering whether there was some sort of idiom or better way to do this:

```
def func(x):
    # if x == 0:
    if True:
        print("Test")
```

Comment: I guess there is no solution for your problem. A good IDE maybe can help you to indent multiple lines at the same time.

Comment: Interesting question. `if True:` seems to be the closest you'll get to this behaviour but some other statement might work better

Comment: I do not have an answer, but I would argue that adding something like `force_indent:` is just as slow as reindenting. Plus on some IDEs you can indent a whole section at once. In Spyder you can do tab or shift+tab to indent or unindent.

Comment: I would comment out the if and then ad an if true. It is the safest

Comment: well solution seems obvious to me: do not comment code at all, if you are using debugger then you can change condition from `x == 0` to `__debug__ or x == 0`

Comment: @Guimoute The problem is not that I find reindentation to be slow. Rather, I would like to avoid reindenting my code at all because it may introduce errors later when I take back that comment. This example is trivial, but with more complex code containing multiple levels of indentation it can become a ready source of errors.

Comment: `if True: # x==0:` seems like the easiest approach.

Comment: You could also use `if 1:` if you want to type fewer characters. But as @khelwood says `if 1: # x==0:` would be neater.

Comment: @khelwood, I like your comment. If you'd formulate it into an answer, I'd accept it. It's basically what I suggested already, but I don't feel like accepting my own answer.

Comment: @Cerno Happy to. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach, it seems to me, is to insert `True: #` into your `if` statement.

So

```
if x==0:
```

becomes

```
if True: # x==0
```

Your indentation can stay the same, and the old condition is still clear and easy to go back to.